# change datetime format in python

Tags: python, django

I am getting this datetime in this format from my database.

```
2016-09-13T08:46:59.953948+00:00
```

I want to change this date into format like

```
13 sep 2016 08:46:59
```

I have used datetime module like

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(2016-09-13T08:46:59.953948+00:00, 'changing format')
```

But it is giving error

```
TypeError at /admin/help
must be string, not datetime.datetime
```

Comment: you should use strftime, because you are formatting time, not parsing it.

Comment: I have also used strftime,but did not work. can i plz get the exact code here ?

Comment: your_datetime_object.strftime('%d %b %y %H:%M%S')

Comment: `strptime()` is to **parse** a string, producing a `datetime` object. Django has [Django-specific datetime format configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT) and template filters for [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date) and [time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-time); have you tried using that yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the timezone and milliseconds you can try by the following function:

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse_db_time_string(time_string):
    date = datetime.strptime(time_string.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    return datetime.strftime(date, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

You can call the function with your db strings then simply like this:

```
old_time_string = '2016-09-13T08:46:59.953948+00:00'
new_time_string = parse_db_time_string(old_time_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

By importing Datetime and Arrow you can convert into your required format. Arrow is a python library to format date & time.

```
import arrow
import datetime

today = arrow.utcnow().to('Asia/Calcutta').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
'2016-09-13 15:57:38'

current_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%d-%B-%Y %H:%M:%S')
'13-September-2016 15:57:38'
```

To know more about Arrow https://micropyramid.com/blog/python-arrow-to-show-human-friendly-time/

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
import datetime
# n is your time as shown in example
your_time = n.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

When trying to make human readable format I recommend [django humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/humanize/)